How to use Pycharm's debugger while running pyautogui script?
I have a Python script that uses pyautogui to control the mouse and perform some tasks on my computer. However there is something wrong and I would like to debug the code.
I'm trying to use Pycharm's debugger step by step, but when I do so, the cursor focus goes to Pycharm and the code can't run as it should.
Is it possible to run the debugger in the background? Or is there a workaround? Other tools?
I've tried to rescale Pycharm's window, but it didn't work as well.
